# Accessing Adobe Edge Animate instance through jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, adobe-edge

Am trying to do two things here, outside of the Edge animation.

**The scene**
3 boys in idle status.

**Action**

- Click on any of the boy.
- Replace 'opened' mouth PNG with a 'closed' mouth PNG.

Am trying to bind each character using jQuery in my HTML page through

```
$(this).on('click', function (){ 
   //Close the mouth
});
```

The code am using is from the documentation (which has limited description on how to access animate instance through jQuery).

```
var comp = AdobeEdge.getComposition("act0_introduction");
var stage = comp.getStage();
console.log("Stage: "+stage);
```

The error am receiving through Chrome is:
`Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'getComposition'`

Answer (score 0):

Try using [jQuery.noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

```
 $.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
// Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
});
// Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
```

Comment: Sadly it doesn't work, i reduced my script the bare minimum and the error still shows up. http://pastebin.com/T8PWtApc